# Access page.tpl.php variables from html.tpl.php

Tags: theming

I've got a well-established theme that's building a lot of variables for the page template, ie. $variables['page']['stripe_color'] = $some_node_data; However, now I'd like to apply this variable to the body tag; so, it needs to be communicated to html.tpl.php

I know there's a bunch of ways to this, store it in a global, reevaluate in the theme_preprocess_html, but I'm wondering if there's a simple variable somewhere that's available that I'm not finding.

Comment: Nope, as far as I know THEME_preprocess_html https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_html/7.x is your only way (Only reasonable way)

Comment: Yes, but are there any common variables in this function that are populated by theme_preprocess_page() ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a perfect use case for the more generic [`hook_preprocess`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7.x):

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess(&variables, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'page' || $hook == 'html') {
    $variables['shared_var'] = 'foo';
  }
}
```

`$shared_var` will be available in both html.tpl.php and page.tpl.php. This will be processed twice, so if it's expensive to build the vars, make sure you statically cache them.

Comment: And I assume $hook == 'page'  is called before  $hook == 'html'?

Comment: Don't have to time to check right now but I'm 99% certain it does, yes